# /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades: Permission denied issue "Even on root"

Tags: upgrade, permissions, root

I have some issue about upgrade ubuntu v22.04 to v22.10. When I type on terminal;

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

I get;

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

And when I typed `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` I face obstacle `permission denied`. If I type `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` on root I couldn't reach `release-upgrade` because of permission obstacle.

Comment: `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` is a config text file, so you can not execute it. `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` will show you the content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great If you help me to change the prompt=lts to prompt=normal.

Comment: I made it by `nano` thanks.